# MySQL Query Of Two Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database with two tables: `members` and `profilefields`.

`members` has the columns: `ID, name, email`
`profilefields` has the columns: `ID, field1, field2, etc.`

I'd like to select the `name` and `email` of each row in `members`, based on a query of `profilefields`

I think this is how it works, but I don't know how to make the query:

Get id from `profilefields` where `field1 = X` AND `field2 = Y`
Get name and email from members for those IDs

I'm really new to this so I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: How are the two tables connected? Is it via the`ID`field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `in` operator:

```
SELECT name, email
FROM   members
WHERE  id IN (SELECT id
              FROM   profilefields
              WHERE  field1 = 'X' and field2 = 'Y')
```

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT
    m.name,
    m.email
FROM
    members m
    INNER JOIN profilefields pf ON
    m.ID = pf.id
WHERE
    pf.field1=X AND
    pf.field2=Y
```

Here we use an `INNER JOIN` in the `FROM` clause to link the tables ON their `id` field. The filter goes into the `WHERE` clause, and the fields you want to bring back are up in the `SELECT` clause.

Answer (score 3):

If those tables related based on ID

```
SELECT m.name, m.email
FROM members m
JOIN profilefields p
ON m.ID=p.ID 
AND p.field1=X 
AND p.field2=Y
```

Comment: I'd upvote if you wouldn't use the syntax that is deprecated since 1992.

Comment: @fancyPants, I am putting the same answer with ANSI92 standard join syntax. Please upvote :)

Comment: I am sorry, probably I don't know something, what's wrong?

Comment: I have edited your answer, to include newer JOIN syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that :

`Select ID, name, email from members where ID in ( Select id from profilefields where field1 = x and field2 =y)`